# How to open wifi settings android with nfc tag?

Tags: android, settings, nfc

I am making an android application that will open a page in the default android settings application.I understand that

```
android.provider.settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS
```

opens up the wifi settings . I need help implementing that as a message for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store arbitrary Intents into an NFC tag; the system wouldn't know what to do with them. You'll need to write a custom payload that launches your application, and then your application will need to manually send the Intent based on your payload.

At a minimum, you'll want to store an AAR record, which will launch your app when the tag is scanned:

```
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
        new NdefRecord[] {
            ...,
            NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.yourapp")}
```

From there, you can add additional `NdefRecord` entries to store whatever extra data you want.

As a practical matter, I recommend not storing the raw Intent as a record. Assuming you're not properly validating the input, somebody could write a similar tag that launches any Activity on the system, which seems at least mildly irresponsible.

More reading:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#creating-records